# It's appreciated, if not loved

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> That it's not loved, only appreciated?
>
> Or oh my goodness I so appreciate this, I might just love it too!

I'm not sure how I should take this.
As a slight middle finger, sarcastic.
Is this said/written with a good vibe, good intentions or the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It's appreciated" => appreciated for sure

"*If* not loved" => It *may* (or may not) be loved.

Usually my understanding of this construction is your second option, "Oh my goodness I so appreciate this, I might just love it too!"

I think it *could* also mean,"Loving is probably an overstatement, but I definitely do appreciate it."

Either way, the comment itself is one of good intentions, and doesn't imply sarcasm or meanness.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick and knowledgeable response Lorel!!